# Is it mandatory to use Secret Manager for storing Microsoft External logIn ClientId and ClientSecret

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, secret-manager

I have followed Microsoft's [instructions on setting up a Microsoft external login for ASP.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2), but I have directly pasted my Client Id and Client Secret in my code's Startup.cs. All works fine, but I am concerned about security. Is this bad practice / not recommended? Or should I definitely use [Secret Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=macos#secret-manager) and reference them from there?

Comment: How is this question opinion based, seriously. All the technologies I am using are owned by Microsoft and they have documentation on Secret Manger in relation to App secrets. Their resources state to `never` store these in code, and state to only use Secret Manager for development only. That's a straight answer by the technology owners themselves. I don't think anyones opinions can count in this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched and found the answer here: [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=macos)

No, it is not mandatory but rather **`strongly recommended`** for security purposes.

Microsoft suggests to `Never store passwords or other sensitive data in source code`, which is common sense, but this resource as a whole incorporates client id's and secrets.

Also, the resource mentions Secret Manager to be used for `Development purposes only`. Storage of the Microsoft App Id (Client Id) and secrets for Production use can be done in Azure Key Vault (development too if you wish).